# Skip builds upon checking in certain types of files

Tags: tfsbuild

Is there any way to skip the builds getting kicked off automatically when certain types of files are checked in? We have a Continuous Integration build definition that kicks off every time we check-in files. We are not doing database builds as of now and using TFS purely as source control for our SQL files. I do not want a build to be kicked off when we check-in these SQL files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following line in the check-in comments:

***NO_CI***

and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks. This answers a lot of other questions I had.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't doing anything with the DB as part of a build, you could "cloak" the folder(s) that contain the DB source in the build definition workspace. The will hide the checkin from the build and stop the checking starting a build

Comment: Interesting. I will check this out.